# GUI components disappearing when resizing

Tags: java, swing, paint

I'm writing a program that trades out the main component of the GUI when a button is pressed. To do this, I have multiple classes extending a component (JScrollPane) that can then be placed into my main class, which extends JFrame.

```
JScrollPane menu;

public MenuSystem()
{
  menu = new OpeningMenu(this);
  setSize(500,500);
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  setTitle("Menu system");
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  loadInfo();
  pane = getContentPane();
  pane.setLayout(null);
  pane.add(menu);
  setVisible(true);
}

public void changeMenuTo(JScrollPane x)
{
  pane.remove(menu);
  menu = x;
  pane.add(menu);
  pane.repaint();
}
```

These bits of code control which JScrollPane is displayed on the GUI. I face two problems that I believe are related.

1. When I start the program, some of the components in the initial JScrollPane do not appear. I have several buttons and a JLabel in this pane, but only the first button appears. The rest of the buttons will appear when my mouse passes over them, but until then, they are invisible. This seems strange, because it suggests that my constructor is somehow at fault. when bringing up the same pane with the changeMenuTo() method, it appears perfectly.
2. Whenever I manually resize the screen, all components in the current pane disappear. It happens almost exactly like when I first start the program, buttons are invisible until my mouse passes over them. In this case the first button is also invisible.

Comment: You've not posted a valid [mcve], a small program that we can actually compile, run and modify, so it will be difficult if not impossible to tell you exactly why your program is not working, other than to say that with this code: `pane.setLayout(null);`, you are shooting yourself in the foot. As answers to so many Swing questions on this site will tell you, using a null layout is dangerous if not foolish and will lead to hard to debug errors and difficult to create and maintain GUI's.

Comment: 2) you really want to use a [CardLayout]((http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)).

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null)` is your first issue

Comment: Why dose your components extend from JScrollPane, seems like a strange idea to me. You may also consider looking into CardLayout instead

Answer (score 0):

Changing the layout has fixed the issue. Thanks for the suggestions.